# What are the drawbacks of using a ferrite inductor in a boost converter circuit

Tags: inductor, buck-boost

I have dissected a [boost converter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/MT3608-DC-DC-Voltage-Step-Up-Adjustable-Boost-Converter-Power-Supply-Module-2A-2V-24V-DC/32915574997.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.59.5d701a25rXN6vV&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2_10065_10068_10130_10547_319_10548_317_10696_10192_10190_453_10084_454_10083_10618_431_10307_10820_10301_10821_10303_537_536_10059_10884_5736015_10887_100031_321_322_10103_5736115,searchweb201603_54,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=3a4fb5b3-e15f-454e-88bb-45cafcbc6f41-8&algo_pvid=3a4fb5b3-e15f-454e-88bb-45cafcbc6f41) so I can remake it on my own PCB. It works fine but I am now experimenting with using different inductors to reduce the overall footprint. I tried installing a ferrite inductor which I had lying around. I don't even know what value it has but to my surprise it seemed to work and held a relatively stable voltage when I attached a motor to the circuit.

What are the drawbacks of using one of these because they are smaller and easier to solder than coils and so it seems like a no brainer to use them although I’m sure there must be reasons not to...

Comment: You need to take two steps back. The inductor is a critical part of your converter and you need to design it accordingly. Use known cores with datasheets and compute inductance, inductance under load, saturation current and power losses. Adjust to fit your design specification. _”don't even know what value it has but to my surprise it seemed to work and held a relatively stable voltage when I attached a motor to the circuit.”_ That’s a recepie for disaster. Ferrite instead of iron powder cores has their place for boost converters, depending on operating mode and frequency. What are yours?

Comment: I should add that i am a hobbyist and so my knowledge has large gaps. what kind of disaster might happen?

Comment: Mainly broken transistors and diodes. But fear not! It's only a few formulas you need to learn. IL=NAB is the most important. I is your peak switch current (not output current). L is your inductance. N is your number of turns. A is the cross section area of your core. B is your peak flux density. All units in SI. If you have that covered, you have come a very long way in designing your boost inductor. Next lesson would be power loss calculation.